# callback for kill child_process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I use `server = child_process.spawn('node', ['app.js']);` to start a node server.
And I kill this process by doing `server.kill('SIGKILL');`

I want to do some cleaning up in `app.js`, like close the db connection, before the server process been killed, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Catch the event and do your cleanup inside. Also, use SIGTERM since SIGKILL can't be cached as [@Dan D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388787/dan-d) pointed.

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function handleSigterm() {
    db.close();
    //more cleanup code
    //then truly exit.
    process.exit();
});
```

This must be done in your app.js file.

Comment: But SIGKILL can't be caught, the process will die before that is possible. But SIGTERM would work.

Comment: got `Error: uv_signal_start EINVAL`, as stated here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6339

Comment: Nice catch @DanD. I will add a recommendation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tree-kill](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-tree-kill#examples) module. Using it you can provide a callback that will be called once the process is killed.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const kill = require('tree-kill');

const server = spawn('node', ['app.js']);

kill(server.pid, 'SIGKILL', function(err) {
    // Do things
});
```